# Why is the size applied to the custom view not reflected?

Tags: android

The code at the bottom is a custom button code. (custom_button_view.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/bg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/symbol"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="my custom button view"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

You can clearly see that the height of the custom button is set to `wrap_content`. And I set the custom button in `MainActivity`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.ez.customview.CustomButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        app:back="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        app:sym="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_alert"
        app:text="This is Custom Button view" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="TEST BUTTON" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

But in real activity, it doesn't applied custom button view height size. Why this happen? And how to I get fix??

[Edit]
Here is `CustomButton` class.

```
class CustomButton : LinearLayout {
    private var bg: LinearLayout? = null
    private var symbol: ImageView? = null
    private var text: TextView? = null

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        initView(context)
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
        initView(context)
        getAttrs(attrs)
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleInt: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleInt) {
        initView(context)
        getAttrs(attrs, defStyleInt)
    }

    private fun initView(context: Context) {
        val v = View.inflate(context, R.layout.custom_button_view, this)
        val view = (context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater).inflate(R.layout.custom_button_view, this, false)
        addView(view)

        bg = findViewById(R.id.bg)
        symbol = findViewById(R.id.symbol)
        text = findViewById(R.id.text)
    }

    private fun getAttrs(attrs: AttributeSet) {
        val typedArray = context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomButton, 0, 0)

        setTypeArray(typedArray)
    }

    private fun getAttrs(attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) {
        val typedArray = context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomButton, defStyle, 0)

        setTypeArray(typedArray)
    }

    private fun setTypeArray(array: TypedArray) {
        try {
            bg?.setBackgroundResource(array.getResourceId(R.styleable.CustomButton_back, android.R.color.holo_blue_bright))
            symbol?.setImageResource(array.getResourceId(R.styleable.CustomButton_sym, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email))
            text?.setTextColor(array.getColor(R.styleable.CustomButton_textColor, ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.black)))
            text?.text = array.getString(R.styleable.CustomButton_text)
        } finally {
            array.recycle()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you use the layout inspector to see from where the button is getting the extra height? also if possible share the corresponding codes of the custom button class

Comment: No; I didn't use the layout inspector because I don't know how to use. But I'll find the way to use immediately. And I add my custom button class code.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be caused by this line:
`symbol?.setImageResource(array.getResourceId(R.styleable.CustomButton_sym, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email))`
You set the image as ic_dialog_email, so your custom button is the same size as that image.
I'm not sure though

Comment: Thank you for your advice but the result is same when I remove that line... I think it doesn't matter because I set the ```ImageView``` "symbol" width and height to 40dp each other at the first time. Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: Then try removing one line, then see if result changes. If not, then restore it and remove a different line.